# Ubuntu 14.0 VM (VirtualBox) on Windows 7 host not connecting to internet

Tags: 14.04

I am posting this question after going through numerous threads here.

I have windows 7 (host) and Ubuntu 14.0 LTS VM (Guest) running on VirtualBox. In the virtualbox network settings for this Guest VM, I have enabled NAT. This is my office environment, therefore, I have set the proxy address manually through the "network settings" within Ubuntu.

I can ping to the proxy server successfully, however, I am unable to connect to internet or browse any website from firefox. I am also not able to use apt-get command which always shows me unable to connect to "proxy server". Can anyone please help me understand. I have also tried to enter the proxy address inside 95proxies under /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ but the error remains the same. Can anyone please help me understand this issue.

(Edit)

**ifconfig**

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:39:9f:4c
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe39:9f4c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:122 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:710 (710.0 B)  TX bytes:14443 (14.4 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:183 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:183 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:13016 (13.0 KB)  TX bytes:13016 (13.0 KB)

**route -n**

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

**ping 8.8.8.8**

PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.

[there was no result. The ping got stuck with the above message]

Comment: If you use "NAT" you should use DHCP on your guest.
It will get an IP address from the DHCP service from VirtualBox.
The natting will happen there.

Comment: Where do I configure DHCP?

Comment: You said:
_I have set the proxy address manually through the "network settings" within Ubuntu._
Where did you do that?

Comment: I manually set the proxy from "System Settings -> Network->Network Proxy" . I do not see any DHCP configuration there.

Comment: On your "Network Proxy", you choose "none"
On the "Wired" connection, choose Option -> IPv4 -> DHCP

Comment: I have done this but It is not working. It is the same problem.

Comment: Ok, give the output of 
`ifconfig` `route -n` and `ping 8.8.8.8`

Comment: I have added these details as Edit in the main post.

Comment: Have you tried using the bridged adapter setting to see if the same issue occurs?

Comment: @Schyken I have tried bridging, but there is no difference with the error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this:

> On the WIN7 machine's own "Local Area Connection",
>   "Properties">>"Sharing", and check "Allow other network users ...".
>   And "OK"

and restart your vm machine.
The problem is that your windows is not natting.

Comment: I have tried this, but not working. I am getting the same issue.